# CSS // universal/crossplatform css code

Tags: css, cross-browser, cross-platform, platform

I have since the beginning been annoyed with the compatibility of CSS. Whats the best practice for coding css, that works with the most common platforms... 
( IE7+, Firefox, Safari, Chrome AND iPad / iPhone, Blacberry, Android)

Are there any list to be found anywhere with known differences ?

Thanks! 
Jakob

Comment: we have the same issue in our new web application, all JS code is written in JQuery which saves us from scripting errors and gives us almost 100% cross browser and cross platform compatibility. Still CSS layout management can be different... :(

Comment: Yeah, jQuery is great for cross platform applications, maybe someone should make a css library, that alters all css code to work with all browsers : )

Comment: [Wikipedia - Comparison of layout engines (CSS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_(Cascading_Style_Sheets))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I often use CSS reference on http://www3.w3schools.com/cssref/default.asp - for each css element, they give the compatibility list of various browsers and also unique behaviour of some, if applicable.

For example, have a look at http://www3.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp for `display` property.  It shows that the property is supported in all browser, and then gives details of specifics of IE:

> The values "inline-table", "run-in", "table", "table-caption",
>   "table-cell", "table-column", "table-column-group", "table-row",
>   "table-row-group", and "inherit" is not supported in IE7 and earlier.
>   IE8 requires a !DOCTYPE. IE9 supports the values.

Similar description is provided for all other CSS elements.  I'm not sure if it will address all of your issues, but it certainly is a very good resource.